# Avel that needs shmira -- Also on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, mourning-aveilus

That which we say an Avel (person in mourning) is among the people that need "shmirah" (Someone to be with them - See [Gemorah Brachos 54b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=54b&format=pdf) at the bottom) is this also on Shabbos? Normally we say that Yisael doesn't need "shmirah" on Shabbos since the Shabbos itself protects them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SA HaRav in OC Siman 267 Sif 5 writes that we don't end of the bracha of "Hashkivanu" Friday night (before Shemoneh Esrei) with the ending "Shomer Amo Yisrael" like we do during the week because Yisrael (as a whole) doesn't need "Shmirah" on Shabbos. The Shabbos itself is what "guards" us.
However he does say at the end of the sif that a Yachid *does* need Shmirah on Shabbos.

From here we could say then that those mentioned in the Gemorah in Brachos Daf 54b that need "Shmirah" would need not only during the week but also on Shabbos.

Comment: Nice idea, though not a very strong argument. +1.

Comment: @msh210 Thanks. But this seems rather pashut. Look at the SA HaRav inside. What else does it mean that a individual/yachid needs shmirah?!? (If not l'inyun these things that the gemorah says need "shmirah") what other inyun of "shmirah" is there that a yachid would need and in what case. What could it be applied to?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose.

Comment: @msh210 This question was originally asked of me by my Rebbe HaRav Shammai Gross Shlit"a (bal machaber ShuT Shevat HaKahasi) from the Gedolei HaPoskim in Eretz Yisrael. I later found this teretz in the Shulchan Aruch HaRav b'siyata dishmaya and he had a lot of haneh from it Baruch HaShem.